# Update to state does not get displayed in component in Redux

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, reducers

I update transcriptDisplay in reducer(I have a method on button click to update the state). I can see it getting updated in state tree.

```
 case actions.TRANSCRIPT_GET:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    transcriptDisplay: action.payload,
  });
```

But it doesnt get rendered on view. This is the view part:

```
    {this.props.activeVideo.transcriptDisplay && this.props.activeVideo.transcriptDisplay.map(transcript => (
      transcript.text
    ))}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the React/redux binding - if so, what does your `connect` call look like?

Answer (score 0):

funkadelic (cool name) when mapping over objects,  use `return` and wrap transcript.text in a react node i.e.

```
{this.props.activeVideo.transcriptDisplay && this.props.activeVideo.transcriptDisplay.map((transcript, i) => (
      return <div key={i}>{transcript.text}</div>
    ))}
```

Give it a go, you should see output

Comment: I do have the return statement. I figured the issue. It was because of a high level wrapper that wasnt passing down the props